# Instance only when needed - GCP

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, push-queue

I have a video editing task that needs to be completed occasionally. The task is relatively intensive and therefore needs a powerful machine to do it. It can take up to about 10 minutes to complete. I might get 10-20 such requests per day, though that will increase in the future.

I have created a docker container that currently is a consumer that pulls jobs from [PubSub](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-python). I was thinking to have an instance of this container on [Google Container Engine](https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/). However, as I understand it, I would need to have at least one instance of this (large / powerful / expensive) container running at all times, even if the majority of time it is sat idle. Therefore my cost for running this service would be overly high until my usage increased.

Is there an alternative way of running my container (GCP or otherwise) where I push a job to some service, which then starts an instance of a powerful machine, processes the job, then shuts down? Therefore I am paying for my CPU hours used.

Comment: [Serverless Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/) is actually what you need.

Comment: Yea, I think Cloud Functions would be an ideal solution. If they supported running a docker container (e.g. python wrapping FFmpeg) I would be sorted. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the cluster autoscaler: https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/cluster-autoscaler

Comment: To me it looks like cluster autoscaler is going to require me to have at least one node, no?